# Why doesn't GNU make output the execution of my command?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a GNU makefile with a target which (simplified) looks like this:

```
determineversion:
    $(eval GITDESCRIBE := $(shell git describe --dirty))

anothertarget: determineversion
    do-something $(GITDESCRIBE)
```

When I run `make anothertarget`, this works as expected (I get the value of `git describe` passed into `do-something` that I expected). However, I see no output from the `git describe` command. I assume this is because I am capturing the output with the `:=` operator? How can I echo this output as part of this expression?

***Update 2015-07-13***: Fixed my code. Very sorry, but I missed out the dependency from anothertarget, which is crucial to understanding this question.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the `determineversion` target to show the output from `git describe` as well as set it into the make variable? Or something else?

Comment: Follow the first rule of using `eval`:  don't use `eval` :).  If you end up needing enough magic in your makefile that `eval` makes sense, you'll know it.  Here, it's just confusing you.  The first example in Corey Brenner's answer below is what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to set the GITDESCRIBE variable with the output, but also show that process being executed (it is currently hidden).

Answer (score 1):

If you reformulate your makefile as such:

```
GITDESCRIBE := $(shell git --describe)

determineversion:
[TAB]@echo "GITDESCRIBE: '${GITDESCRIBE}'"

anothertarget:
[TAB]do-something ${GITDESCRIBE}
```

You'll be successful.  Alternatively,

```
determineversion:
[TAB]$(eval GITDESCRIBE := $(shell git --describe))

anothertarget: determineversion
[TAB]do-something ${GITDESCRIBE}
```

Might be the magic you're looking for.

Comment: Corey, the second of your answers is the code I have already (I missed out the dependency at first, I fixed my Q). The issue is that this still doesn't echo the process of executing the shell command. It prints the result, but only *after* it's completed; suitable in this case, but not suitable if `git --describe` were a long-running command.

Comment: The only caveat here is that if you don't *always* need the value of `GITDESCRIBE` this makefile still always runs it (because of the `:=` assignment). If you don't always need it *but* only need it **once** when you do need it then you can use `GITDESCRIBE = $(shell ...)` instead to avoid calling `git` when you don't use it (but this will call git **every** time you use the variable so if you use it more than once this is potentially worse).

Answer (score 0):

If I write a simple makefile like yours:

```
foo:
[TAB]$(eval FOO := abc)

bar:
[TAB]@echo "FOO: '${FOO}'"
```

I get "FOO: ''" when I run "make -f foo.mk bar"

However, if I replace [TAB] with eight spaces, I get: "FOO: 'abc'", as you describe.

If "$(eval ...)" is not prefixed with [TAB] (or your ${.RECIPEPREFIX}), it is considered inline GNU Make grammar, and is not considered part of the recipe.